# PHP array merge issues , multilevel array merge into single level

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, merge

Here is my output: im using more foreach loop with different condition and values put into same array name `$returnVal[]=`

EX:

```
foreach($val1 as $vals)
{
      $returnVal[]=$vals;
}




foreach($val2 as $vals)
  {
      $returnVal[]=$vals;
  }



 foreach($val3 as $vals)
  {
      $returnVal[]=$vals;
   }



 foreach($val4 as $vals)
   {
      $returnVal[]=$vals;
   } `
```

Im getting Output:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 39705--COLUMBUS--LOWNDES--MS
                [1] =>  39702--COLUMBUS--LOWNDES--MS
                [2] =>  39710--COLUMBUS--LOWNDES--MS
                [3] =>  39701--COLUMBUS--LOWNDES--MS
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 39705--COLUMBUS--LOWNDES--MS
                        [1] =>  39702--COLUMBUS--LOWNDES--MS
                        [2] =>  39710--COLUMBUS--LOWNDES--MS
                        [3] =>  39701--COLUMBUS--LOWNDES--MS
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 39705--COLUMBUS--LOWNDES--MS
                        [1] =>  39702--COLUMBUS--LOWNDES--MS
                        [2] =>  39710--COLUMBUS--LOWNDES--MS
                        [3] =>  39701--COLUMBUS--LOWNDES--MS
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 39705--COLUMBUS--LOWNDES--MS
                                [1] =>  39702--COLUMBUS--LOWNDES--MS
                                [2] =>  39710--COLUMBUS--LOWNDES--MS
                                [3] =>  39701--COLUMBUS--LOWNDES--MS
                            )

                    )

                [2] => 57038--JEFFERSON--UNION--SD
            )

        [3] => 57049--NORTH SIOUX CITY--UNION--SD
    )
```

My Question: remove duplicate values and merge into one level

Answer (score 1):

Push element if it is not exists in the result array, this will avoid duplicate entries. Try the code below,

```
$returnVal = [];
foreach($val1 as $vals)
{
    if (!in_array($vals, $returnVal)) {
        $returnVal[]=$vals;
    }

} ..etc and so on
```

Comment: @karthik : your required result is not mentioned here, and not a word about $val2,3.. arrays . If you  clarify then I can help you better.

Comment: `foreach($stateSearch as $res4)   
    {
      $where = ' state="'.$res4.'" ';
      $return =$this->cityCountyZip_Return($cleansedObName,$where);
      $ZipLists[]=$this->returnZipValues($return,  $ZipLists);
    }` this is my code